# Stream Windows console output to Android device

Tags: android, windows, cmd, stream, console

I'm not sure if the question is correctly written.

Let's say I have a CMD running on my computer. It's showing some random data. Can I do anything to copy that data and stream to an Android device? Maybe using wifi or something.

I can do it manually, just copy and paste into a txt, and send that txt to the device, so it should be possible to stream too.

Thanks.

EDIT: I can't edit the program. But I can access to the log files.

Comment: I am about to leave, but if no one gives you a complete answer, i will do mock up on some code, but if the log file is .txt just pipe that using dataoutputstream (send a byte, and user writeUTF) and on the android end listen for that byte, and readUTF. I usually use this method to send commands to other devices.

Comment: @andyADD I'm trying to read the files from the device using a simple local FTP server. It's going well.

However, I'm still curious about streaming an existing CMD session.

Answer (score 0):

no dont copy and paste it. before you do anything in cmd do this:

```
cmd /k C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe > C:/Users/%username%/Desktop/CommandLogs.txt
```